# Why does $G$ have to be a finite group? (Sylow theory question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I am trying to show that if $G$ is a finite group, and $P$ is a normal Sylow $p$-sugroup of $G$,  then $P$ is characteristic in $G$.

I think this is pretty straightforward: Since $P$ is a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, it must be the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.  So, if $\sigma\in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, we have $\sigma(P)=P$, since automorphisms of $G$ permute Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.  Thus, $P$ is characteristic in $G$.  My question is (assuming I didn't miss a detail in the proof), where does the finiteness of $G$ come into play?

Comment: What is your definition of Sylow subgroup for an infinite group?

Comment: Ah, duh.  This is definitely a case of overthinking without thinking at all :)
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is a fairly natural one, though, and lots of people have looked for infinitary analogues of the sylow theorems. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110373/sylow-theorems-for-infinite-groups) for some references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural extension of a Sylow $p$-subgroups to infinite groups is to define a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ to be a a maximal (with respect to inclusion) $p$-subgroup subgroup $P$ of $G$, where a $p$-subgroup is defined to be one in which the order of every element of $P$ is a power of $p$.

With that definition, a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ is indeed characteristic, because it consists of all elements of $G$ whose order is a power of $p$.

To see that, just note that if $g \in G$ has a power of $P$ then, for any $h \in P$, we have $(gh)^{p^k} \in P$ for some $k$, and so $gh$ has order a power of $p$, and hence $\langle g, P \rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup and so $g \in P$ by maximality of $P$.

But note that Sylow's theorem does not hold in infinite groups without further assumptions. Sylow subgroups exist by Zorn's lemma, but  there are examples in which they are not all conjugate.